# Can I use a wildcard ssl cert for subdomains, with let's encrypt for bare & www?

Tags: ssl-certificate, https, lets-encrypt

Our main site is hosted with free LE certs included. We have several subdomains on different hosting providers and our own servers that need https. Can we keep the main/www LE cert as is, and get a wildcard cert for the others?

Comment: Why don't you just get a wildcard from Let's Encrypt and use it everywhere you need it?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I could, but it's a different team on the main marketing site, and they would rather have the hosting provider just take care of it.

Answer (score 1):

The Short answer is: Yes you can.

I use this solution, even I own a LE wildcard certificate.
On some other specific domains, a standard certificate

A long answer is not needed IMHO